# Change title legend when use ggplot2 stat_sum

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to change the title legend of a `ggplot2` graph who's build with `stat_sum`.
Here `stat_sum`do not use the proportions but the sum.

The data:

```
data <- structure(list(replicate = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
conc = c(0, 0, 0, 0.074, 0.074, 0.074, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.66, 0.66, 0.66), time = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), Nsurv = c(18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Nrepro = c(161L, 102L, 
128L, 151L, 73L, 60L, 98L, 52L, 123L, 0L, 5L, 0L), conc2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.074, 0.074, 0.074, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.66, 0.66, 
0.66)), .Names = c("replicate", "conc", "time", "Nsurv", 
"Nrepro", "conc2"), row.names = c(43L, 44L, 45L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
133L, 134L, 135L, 178L, 179L, 180L), class = "data.frame")
```

I create the `ggplot`object with:

```
sp <- ggplot(data,aes(conc2, Nsurv)) +
stat_sum(aes(size = factor(..n..))) +
labs(x = "concentration",
y = "response")
```

I tried different functions to change the title legend without results:

```
sp + guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "points")) #no change
#or
sp + guides(color=guide_legend(title = "points")) #no change
sp + scale_fill_discrete(name = "points") #no change
#or
sp + guide_legend(title="points") #don't work
#or
sp + scale_colour_brewer(name = "points") #no change
#or
sp + scale_colour_hue("points") #no change
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to change the name of the size scale for a factor. Thus you need to pass the parameter to `scale_size_discrete`:

```
sp <- ggplot(data,aes(conc2, Nsurv)) +
  stat_sum(aes(size = factor(..n..))) +
  labs(x = "concentration",
       y = "response") +
  scale_size_discrete(name = "points")
```